# Rewrite .htaccess regex url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file with this: (I didn't write it)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?bla=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Problem** URL http://localhost/index/test
The "index" part seems to match "index.php" that's in a web dir and Rewrite fails.

**Question**: What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite fails"?  You're matching anything and routing it to index.php?bla=anything, so maybe you're getting confused about what's going on?  print_r($_GET) in index.php and see if bla is set.

Comment: I don't want "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f" to be true when index is in the URL, the file is not called "index" it's called "index.php".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enabled option [*MultiViews*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) could cause this behavior. Try to disable it:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?bla=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Made the CSS file not load. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You need an exclude files and directory. Your rule means, that it has to be a file or a directory.